# node-gyp linking issue for xcode solution

Tags: c++, xcode, node.js, linker, v8

I am generating a solution with node-gyp for xcode under MacOS using:

```
node-gyp configure -- -f xcode
```

So for so good, the solution gets generated properly, but it doesn't seem to link properly when building it in xcode, it is complaining about v8 undefined symbols. I am using node 0.10.28.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "v8::HandleScope::RawClose(v8::internal::Object**)", referenced from:
      v8::Local<v8::String> v8::HandleScope::Close<v8::String>(v8::Handle<v8::String>) in binding.o
  "v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()", referenced from:
      Method(v8::Arguments const&) in binding.o
  "v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()", referenced from:
      Method(v8::Arguments const&) in binding.o
  "v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction()", referenced from:
      void node::SetMethod<v8::Handle<v8::Object> >(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, char const*, v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Arguments const&)) in binding.o
  "v8::FunctionTemplate::New(v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Arguments const&), v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Signature>)", referenced from:
      void node::SetMethod<v8::Handle<v8::Object> >(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, char const*, v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Arguments const&)) in binding.o
  "v8::Object::Set(v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::Handle<v8::Value>, v8::PropertyAttribute)", referenced from:
      void node::SetMethod<v8::Handle<v8::Object> >(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, char const*, v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Arguments const&)) in binding.o
  "v8::String::New(char const*, int)", referenced from:
      Method(v8::Arguments const&) in binding.o
  "v8::String::NewSymbol(char const*, int)", referenced from:
      void node::SetMethod<v8::Handle<v8::Object> >(v8::Handle<v8::Object>, char const*, v8::Handle<v8::Value> (*)(v8::Arguments const&)) in binding.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried to generate a CMake project that creates a nodejs extension and I am getting the same linking errors. What is the magic twist to link under MacOS with v8/node?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally the magic trick was to use

```
-undefined dynamic_lookup
```

as a linker flag.